# How to install a bot from the world Championship in the the Torcs racing game?

Tags: java, c++, simulation, torcs

I am trying to install one of the champions of the car simulator game Torcs so I can select it as an AI-driver. However no matter what tutorial I follow (for example [here](http://www.berniw.org/aboutme/publications/torcs.pdf)), there is always some problems that the steps that are listed there do not result in the driver being listed in the Torcs program with GUI. As I can't really pinpoint where the problem lies, I hope someone can clear up the steps in order to achieve this.

A slightly similar question was asked [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/torcs/mailman/message/29935897/) but without success. Could someone please post a step by step solution to how to get a driver from [here](http://www.berniw.org/trb/events/event_view.php?vieweventid=20) installed in the Torcs program so that you can actually see how it is being run and run against it? That would help out a lot.

Some steps I have taken:

1. Install driver from [here](http://www.berniw.org/trb/events/event_view.php?vieweventid=20)
2. Follow the steps in the README file in the installed driver folder on how to install the driver. In specific:
3. `tar xvjf hymie_2015.tar.bz2 -C $TORCS_BASE/src/drivers`
4. `cd $TORCS_BASE/src/drivers/hymie_2015`
5. `make clean`
6. `make install`

At step 5 I'm stuck with this approach as there is no `make clean` command in the makefile. You can get this to work when running `export MAKE_DEFAULT=$TORCS_BASE/Make-default.mk`. However then 6th step will fail. I also tried to run `.configure` and `make clean`, `make`, `make install` in the main directory of Torcs (as a process of trial and error), with no result either.

So in short, what are the steps to be taken to download and install a bot so that it becomes visible in the GUI of Torcs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install torcs in usr/src/torcs
make will look for make-default in TORCS_BASE if it's not in usr/src/torcs you will get error(create manually and decompress inside that directory to get
usr/src/torcs/torcs1.xxxx)